# What are the risks of an unauthorised device connected to a mobile hotspot?

Tags: mobile, hotspot

My friend had to activate a mobile hotspot on his iphone for half an hour in an airport to connect his laptop, and suddenly he realized that his device was not the only one connected to it.

What are the risks of someone else's unauthorized connection to the hotspot?
Any advice on using hotspots in public places?

Comment: *"Any advice on using hotspot in public places?"* - set a secure password for the hotspot so that others cannot connect to it.

Comment: Connect the laptop to the phone using USB?

Comment: The risks are the same as being on the same wifi network as an unauthorised device.